# Custom autolayout constraints broken when adding a controller's view programmatically

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a myController that I insert in code, (in self = a root view controller) this way :

```
    MyViewController* myController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:myController];
    [self.view addSubview:myController.view];
    myController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 504, 320, 216);
```

In the xib file of MyViewController, I just have 2 views, one on top of the other. Lets say the top view is called View1, and the bottom view View2. View0 is the main view.

I have added the following vertical NSLayoutConstraints :
    V:[View2(40)]
    V:|-(0)-View1   (Names: '|':View0 )
    V:View2-(0)-|   (Names: '|':View0 )
    V:View1-(0)-View2

That is to say View1 touches View0 on top, and View2 on bottom. And View2 touches View1 on top, View0 on bottom, and has a constant height of 40.

When I run this in portrait, every thing seems ok. But when I rotate to landscape, I have sometime the following error.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xd17cc00 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0xd174a30(268)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9469890 V:[View2(40)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9468e90 V:|-(0)-View1   (Names: '|':View0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9468ef0 V:View2-(0)-|   (Names: '|':View0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x94676f0 V:View1-(0)-View2>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x9450640 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0000.height == UIView:0xd174a30.height - 268>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9469890 V:[View2(40)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Does anybody understands why this I happening ? And what I should do to keep my defined constraints as prior ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so finally, to solve this issue, I had to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO on View0.

Then, to have a good display of my View0, I had to create manually NSLayoutConstraint for View0 and add those constraints to View0's superview.

Answer (score 2):

The autoresizing mask is the legacy way to do layout in iOS (prior to auto layout in iOS 6).  There is a property on `UIView` that automatically translates this legacy system into layout constraints called `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` that is `YES` by default.  If you create a view in code (or in some cases using IB) and intend to use auto layout to position it, you should set this property to `NO` to avoid issues like the one you're seeing above.  This is potentially the cause whenever you see those `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` constraint types in your constraint warnings.